# Youtube Analytics API Issue?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-analytics

When reading through the Youtube API, i noticed that the base url for requestions was using version 3 `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v3/`,

However, when i was using the youtube ANalytics API PHP class, the URL being requested was version 1. `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/` is this an issue, or is the PHP library just out of date? I really do not want to have to make another one class (reinvent the wheel), but i am skeptical about using outdated code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem, the current version for the Analytics API is v1, as you can see in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).

Comment: Ok, i must have been directed to the Data API. And thanks for the link as well.